# Добавить новый узел XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq2xml

Создаю XML:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                    new XDeclaration("1.0", "Windows-1251", ""),
                    new XElement("test",
                            new XElement("Theme", Name),
                            new XElement("questionNumbers", new XAttribute("numbers", TotalQuestions),
                            new XElement("question" + TotalQuestions, new XAttribute("text", Question), new XAttribute("true", TrueAnswer),
                                (f.comboBox1.Text == "2" ? new XElement("answer", "1|2") : (f.comboBox1.Text == "3" ? new XElement("answer", "1|2|3") : (f.comboBox1.Text == "4" ? new XElement("answer", "1|2|3|4") : null)))
                            )
                        )
                    ));

var lastQuestionNumbers = doc.Descendants("questionNumbers").Last();
lastQuestionNumbers.AddAfterSelf(
    new XElement("questionNumbers", new XAttribute("numbers", TotalQuestions),
        new XElement("question" + TotalQuestions,
                     new XAttribute("text", Question), new XAttribute("true", TrueAnswer),
            new XElement("answer", "5"))));
```

Таким образом у меня создается XML файл с таким содержимом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне программно, добавить новый `questionNumbers` в уже существующий XML? (пример)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или может лучше сначала "загнать" всё в `List<string>` и потом уже создавать XML файл?

Подскажите, пожалуйста. (желательно с примером :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно как угодно. Например, если вы хотите добавлять по одному, то так:

```
var lastQuestionNumbers = doc.Descendants("questionNumbers").Last();
lastQuestionNumbers.AddAfterSelf(
    new XElement("questionNumbers", new XAttribute("numbers", TotalQuestions),
        new XElement("question" + TotalQuestions,
                     new XAttribute("text", Question), new XAttribute("true", TrueAnswer),
            new XElement("answer", "5"))));
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51864/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd----xml).